# listview is displayed vertically in my code, can be changed to horizontally?

Tags: android, listview

I implemented a listview in my layout:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

and then in my activity I set its adapter:

```
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
mListView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, mListImages));
```

MyAdapter handles the getView and displays the list vertically:

```
images1
images2
....
```

**Can it display the list horizontally? this way:**

```
image1  image2  ....
```

(for sure it should work with scroll and display all the images)

I saw that this result can be achieved with RecycleView and LayoutManager that gets Horizontal as a parameter but I have implemented the ListView already, which doesn't have the method "setLayoutManager". and I need it to work for API 15 and above.

Comment: oh ok, I got it. sorry..

Comment: Please try RecyclerView - The RecyclerView widget is a more advanced and flexible version of ListView https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with RecyclerView :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

and Layout as my_recycler_view.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `orientation`

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

Comment: ListView doesn't have orientation as I noticed and anyway it didn't work for me :\